# ModalViewController delegate confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I need to present a modal view controller and be notified when it is dismissed or notified that I need to dismiss it, looking here I am still confused:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14

I have my mainViewController and myModalView controller and I have the following code that needs to be implemented but not sure where - first up delegate protocal:

```
@protocol DataSyncDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) doneWithSync;
@end
```

which controller.h does this go in? I am assuming my modalViewController.h

second is my implementation:

```
-(void) doneWithSync {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

which controller.m does this go in?  I am assuming my mainViewController.m

I also have the delegate properties that needs to be aded:

```
id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
```

which controller.m does this need to go in?  I am assuming my modalViewController.h

and here is how I am presenting the modalViewController from my MainViewController:

```
DataSyncViewController *dataSyncViewController = [[DataSyncViewController alloc] initWithOptions:FALSE];
dataSyncViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:dataSyncViewController animated:NO];
[dataSyncViewController release];
```

As of right now this gives me the following error:

```
-[DataSyncViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5952e20
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT - HERE IS MY MODAL VIEW CONTROLLER .H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DataSyncDelegate
-(void) doneWithSync;
@end

@interface DataSyncViewController : UIViewController {
    id <DataSyncDelegate>   delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <DataSyncDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

EDIT - MAIN VIEW CONTROLLER .H AND .M

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "DataSyncViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <DataSyncDelegate>{

}

@end
```

HERE IS THE CREATION OF THE MODAL:

```
DataSyncViewController *dataSyncViewController = [[DataSyncViewController alloc] initWithOptions:FALSE];
dataSyncViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:dataSyncViewController animated:NO];
[dataSyncViewController release];
```

HERE IS MY IMPLEMENTATION OF THE DELEGATE:

```
-(void) doneWithSync {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And now everything looks to wire up correctly in the compiler but I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[DataSyncViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59e4b40'
```

Comment: post your mainViewController as well :)

Comment: Should it not be @interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <DataSyncDelegate> instead of DataSyncComplete?

Comment: sorry I was switching the names around trying different stuff - they match properly

Comment: I FORGOT TO SYNTEHSIZE DELEGATE!!!  So sorry I wasted so much of your time!

Comment: LOL I was going to ask, but I never did. My fault as well. No problem happy to help, just wish I had actually asked about it!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main view controller IS the delegate and should implement the protocol. Your modalView has a delegate that it calls when it is being dismissed.

Comment: I understand the concept but I have some code in the wrong place, that's why I tried to be so detailed above - what do I have in the wrong spot here?

Comment: did you declare the @delegate property in DataSyncViewController?

Comment: Yes, I have this in my dataSyncController: id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

Comment: Is your mainViewController implementing the DataSyncDelegate protocol?

Comment: I believe so, like this in the .m file:
-(void) doneWithSync {
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: when I add this to my mainViewCOntroller.h: @interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <DataSyncComplete>  I get a 'Cannot find protocol declaration' error - I am getting so damn frustrated.